# Is there any database with English verb argument structure?

Tags: reference-request, verbs

To simplify -- different verbs require different number of nouns to be complete. Some of arguments may be implicit in the real usage of language. So, my question is there any database containing many verbs (around 1000 verbs) with their argument structure. Or alternatively, a list of papers where argument structure is analyzed for specific verbs from which such database could be compiled.

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless you specify which language(s) you are talking about. The valence of verbs is not invariable cross-linguistically (or even within a language: consider English _eat_ which is transitive or intransitive vs _muchy_, which is usually transitive but can be used intransitively, vs _dine_ which is intransitive.)

Comment: @ColinFine _Muchy_?

Comment: Sorry - _munch_. I really should proofread my comments!

Comment: I changed title, but I guess there is none for any language.

Comment: @ColinFine I did consider if _munch_ was what you meant, but to me that’s the reverse of your description: usually intransitive (generally with a PP with _on_), but can be transitive.

Comment: It always amazes me how people can down-vote reference request question? Are you opposed people learning something?

Comment: Usually I get answers within hours, and this question is not answered yet, that probably means there is no easy answer. the verb makes sentence a sentence, and not a bag of words, the arguments of verb defines verb function, and there is no database that explains the function of the verb. How can I make basic (statistical) experiments about (many-many) sentences (meaning in general, and not finite sample), if I do not have basic information of how they are constructed?

Comment: Is this what you are after? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explanatory_combinatorial_dictionary

Comment: then there's *A Valency Dictionary of English* https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110892581/html and

Comment: also, a very important study (not a database) is *Verb Valency Patterns* by Susen Faulhaber https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110240788/html

Comment: @Alex B. Thanks for suggestions, I need to decipher them, that will take some time.